# How to export the 'issues' data from github and process it?

Tags: curl, github

I've a requirement that I have to pull the list of issues in my GitHub  repository and make a chart out the data. But, I'm stuck at pulling the list of issues from my GitHub repository.

I tried to understand GIT API page but Im really not sure where from I start the work.

If anyone has done such things before, please shed some light on this.

Answer (score 3):

> *I tried to understand GIT API page but Im really not sure where from I start the work.*

You're probably better off using a library to talk to Github in your language of choice rather than starting from scratch. There's a lot of little nuances to the Github API like pagination, caching, rate limiting, an error handling that these libraries take care of for you.

Perl has [Pithub](http://metacpan.org/pod/Pithub) and [Net::Github](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::GitHub) among [others](https://metacpan.org/search?q=github). Ruby has [github_api](https://rubygems.org/gems/github_api/) and so on.

---

If you really want to do it with `curl`, the [Github API overview](https://developer.github.com/v3/) uses `curl` for all its basic examples. Getting the list of issues is pretty easy.

To ["List issues for a repository"](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository) Github says to `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/issues`. That means to make a GET request to `https://api.github.com/` as mentioned in the [Schema docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/#schema) with the path `/repos/:owner/:repo/issues`. You fill in `:owner` and `:repo`.

```
curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/evalEmpire/perl5i/issues'
```

That will get [all the open issues for evalEmpire's perl5i repository](https://github.com/evalEmpire/perl5i/issues) in a big JSON list. You can then use a JSON parser to turn that into a data structure and do whatever you like with it.

You can also add various parameters as part of the query string. This will get all issues updated since the middle of 2016.

```
curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/evalEmpire/perl5i/issues?state=all&since=2016-07-01T00:00:00Z'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the [python script `unbracketed/export_repo_issues_to_csv.py`](https://gist.github.com/unbracketed/3380407) which does export the issues of a project as a csv file (for Excel for instance), using the [GitHub Issue API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/):

You will see the API query used:

```
REPO = '' # format is username/repo
ISSUES_FOR_REPO_URL = 'https://api.github.com/repos/%s/issues' % REPO
r = requests.get(ISSUES_FOR_REPO_URL, auth=AUTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript, use the [octokit/rest.js](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v17) library. Here's a CLI tool that uses that REST API that you can use quickly: [GitHub CSV Tools](https://github.com/gavinr/github-csv-tools).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the python package PyGithub

```
from github import Github
token = Github('personal token key here')
repo = token.get_repo('repo-owner/repo-name')
issues = repo.get_issues(state='all')
for issue in issues:
    print(issue.url)
```

Here I got back the URL, you can get back the content instead if you want by changing the '.URL' part